# Create a JSON string with each row in MySQL database as new array element

Tags: javascript, php, json, database, mysqli

I have a MySQL database ($database) set up, with a table ("gigdata") and column names as follows:

- id
- clientname
- day
- month
- year
- postcode
- status
- entered

Each column name has a few rows of test data under it. I have successfully connected to the database using PHP's mysqli class, as below.

So far, I have written this PHP:

```
//Connect to database
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $username, $password, $database);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "<p>Connected to database</p>";

//Select data from database
$sql = "SELECT id, clientname, day, month, year, postcode, status, entered FROM gigdata";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Create an empty array
$gigarray = array();

//Check data exists, if YES store in array
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $r) {
            array_push($gigarray, $r);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I'm then echoing the JSON string into Javascript, which works fine:

```
var gigdata = <?php echo json_encode($gigarray) ?>;
```

*QUESTION*

My aim is to adapt the original PHP so that the JSON ends up formatted such that:

- **each database row is a new array element**
- **each database column name is the name in each JSON name/value pair**
- **each database field is the value in each JSON name/value pair**

Hope this makes sense, and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: do you mean each row is a new array or a new array element?

Comment: Thanks Simon, I meant "array element". Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a very helpful mysqli function for getting all data from a result, exactly how you want it - [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Try:

```
json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!